# Using QtHostinfo.lookupHost in PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am working on a project where I want to confirm the existence of a host on a local network. In the QtNetwork package in Qt, the `QHostInfo::lookupHost` method is a convenient way of searching for a host without needing to implement any kind of pinging or being dependent on a ping system call. Its asynchronous call makes it convenient to create a dialog waiting for the call to return with a slot in either the dialog or the main program to handle the return.

#### From Qt's Documentation for QHostInfo:

> To look up a host's IP addresses asynchronously, call lookupHost(), which takes the host name or IP address, a receiver object, and a slot signature as arguments and returns an ID. You can abort the lookup by calling abortHostLookup() with the lookup ID...
>
> The slot is invoked when the results are ready. The results are stored in a QHostInfo object. Call addresses() to get the list of IP addresses for the host, and hostName() to get the host name that was looked up.

The documentation from PySide for [`QHostInfo`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtNetwork/QHostInfo.html) details usage of `lookupHost` but I think it might be automatically generated from the Qt documentation as by default, the method `lookupHost` is declared as a private method in the [typesystem definition for QtNetwork](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-archive/blobs/master/PySide/QtNetwork/typesystem_network.xml).

Is there a particular reason that this method is declared private in the PySide implementation? Does it have to do with the asynchronous nature of the call and Python's GIL?

Comment: It's not obvious why `QHostInfo.lookupHost` is missing in PySide. The function *is* there is PyQt4. I would suggest asking about it on the [PySide mailing list](http://lists.pyside.org/listinfo/pyside).

Comment: @ekhumoro That was my next step but I thought I would ask here first in case anyone had some experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not receiving an answer from the PySide boards, I changed the line in my PySide typesystem definition file for QtNetwork so that it reads:

`<modify-function signature="lookupHost(QString,QObject*,const char*)" access="public"/>`

re-compiled PySide and have no issues