# PySide.QtNetwork.QHostInfo have no lookupHost() method but documentation says otherwise

Tags: python, pyside

I was using PySide's `QHostInfo` class to get the IP address from a hostname. But surprisingly the method `lookupHost` do not exists:

```
1 >>> from PySide import QtNetwork

2 >>> h = QtNetwork.QHo
QtNetwork.QHostAddress  QtNetwork.QHostInfo     

2 >>> h = QtNetwork.QHostInfo()

3 >>> h
3 <<< <PySide.QtNetwork.QHostInfo at 0x25e9128>

4 >>> h.
h.HostInfoError    h.UnknownError     h.error            h.hostName         h.lookupId         h.setErrorString   
h.HostNotFound     h.abortHostLookup  h.errorString      h.localDomainName  h.setAddresses     h.setHostName      
h.NoError          h.addresses        h.fromName         h.localHostName    h.setError         h.setLookupId      

4 >>> h.
```

But the [documentation says otherwise](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtNetwork/QHostInfo.html#PySide.QtNetwork.PySide.QtNetwork.QHostInfo.lookupHost)!

what sort of joke is this?

Pax et bonum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using QtHostinfo.lookupHost in PySide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533698/using-qthostinfo-lookuphost-in-pyside)

Comment: Short of recompiling PySide as mentioned in the linked to stackoverflow post, I would suggest using the `socket.gethostbyname()` method in the Python standard library. If you want the lookup to be asynchronous for some reason (aka emit a signal when it is done), put the call to `gethostbyname()` in a QThread. If you do want to go down this route, I suggest asking another stack overflow question on "how to use `socket.gethostbyname()` to duplicate the behaviour of `QHostInfo.lookupHost()`" if you are unsure of how to proceed